# How Content type known in MQTT

Tags: facebook, chat, mqtt

I was just reading [Facebook uses MQTT for chat](http://mqtt.org/2011/08/mqtt-used-by-facebook-messenger), and we know MQTT payload is just a stream of bytes having no header options like HTTP or CoAP. 
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31988877/content-type-alternative-in-mqtt) answers that there should be one topic for each content type.

**My question** is; there are a lot of **MIME** types and how facebook handle them using MQTT?

**Example:** There is a user **A** and a user **B**. User B sends jpg image to A. For correctly identifying content type it must be published under something like **/inboxOfUserA/jpg**. If that is the case then there will be a lot of topics for a single user (as there a lot of content types, and what if a new content type comes in future?).

I am not getting that, there should be some batter way.

Comment: What if that is just a simple text message with URL to the file stored on amazon, so there is still only one topic for a specific user? Maybe chat message does not contain only payload, but additional fields in every message. For example it might contain `type` (chat, image, poke,...), `date`, `payload`, ... and its all sent as a stream of bytes?

Comment: The question you link to does not say there *should* be one topic per type, it's just suggests that is one way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to remember that MQTT is just a messaging transport, what gets carried from publisher to subscriber(s) is entirely in the system designers control.

While a MQTT message payload is just a collection of bytes there is nothing to stop you implementing your own structure within that collection of bytes

e.g.

- A message can contain a header that includes a field similar to a mime type.
- A message could be an XML document that can include all kinds of meta data about it's content